# Draw a image out of the screen but still got click event from screen

Tags: android

I draw a image view out of the screen by rewriting dispatchDraw method, However, the image can still get click event when I click inside the screen.

I have a image view and add it into a custom Layout. for the Layout, I rewrite its dispatchDraw method as below:

```
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.translate((float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight());
      super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
      canvas.translate((float) (-getWidth()), (float) (-getHeight()));
}
```

I show this custom layout using Toast.show(). After that, the image should be invisible because I set the beginning draw position as (width,height) by invoking canvas.translate((float) getWidth(), (float) getHeight()); However, when I click on the screen, I found the image can still got touch event.
My understanding is that since the image is now draw outside the screen, it should not response any touch event inside the screen. But that's not the truth.

Really appreciated if you can explain the reason.
Thanks!

Comment: The `View` itself is still in the same location, with its same dimensions. Merely translating its draw doesn't change those properties. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but why don't you just move the `View`?

Comment: You are using TranslateAnimation to move image. 
**TranslateAnimation** the view which you are animating does not really leave its original position on the screen, it just makes it look like it is moving. So the view basically doesnt change its coordinates.

Use **ObjectAnimator** to change the coordinates of view or **ViewPropertyAnimator**

Comment: Got it now. Really thanks for all your replies. I just happened to find this during my development.